# FCM Messaging Chrome push notifications from service worker click and icon won't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker

This code show my notifications, all is good, but in the notification popup i see no icon, and click notification just close it and not open window. This code i get from this ([Google's tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/handling-messages)).

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    'messagingSenderId': 'my id'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
    var title = '';
    var body = '';

    if(payload && payload.notification) {
        if(payload.notification.body) {
            body = payload.notification.body;

            if(payload.notification.title) {
                title = payload.notification.title;
            }
        }
    }

    return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body: body,
        icon: '/img/logos/logo-short-blue.png'
    });
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();

    var appUrl = '/' + event.notification.data.actionUrl;

    event.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({
            includeUncontrolled: true,
            type: 'window'
        }).then( activeClients => {
            if (activeClients.length > 0) {
                activeClients[0].navigate(appUrl);
                activeClients[0].focus();
            } else {
                clients.openWindow(appUrl);
            }
        })
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `click_action` as url and `icon` fields on server side, while forming payload of push-message.

Answer (score 1):

from google's guide :

> Click actions support only secure HTTPS URLs.